# Google Calendar Feed Missing Events

Tags: rss, google-calendar-api

While beta testing an app that parses a Google Calendar, I noticed a problem with the calendar itself.  Below is the actual Calendar link, along with its corresponding Feed link.  Not all the events listed in the calendar are in the feed.  For example, you will notice that the game on January 29th in Dover is not in the Feed anywhere.  Any thoughts on what may be going on?

[Calendar Itself](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=ocacademy.org_2q91g7ko9qo4sgb1qgg8l9hbpk@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/Chicago)

[Feed](http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ocacademy.org_2q91g7ko9qo4sgb1qgg8l9hbpk@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feed only shows the last 25 edited entries per default. If you want it to show more you have to add something like: ?max-results=1000 after your URL
like this:

```
www.google.com/calendar/feeds/<id>/private-<magic-cookie>/full?max-results=1000
```

Comment: Do you have a source that explains these options?